# Is classification by a semidirect product complete?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

For example, let's say we have to classify groups of a certain order. Can all the groups of that order be expressed as some semi-direct products?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}_4$ is not a semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (there is no section, there's only one subgroup of order $2$, ...), but $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$ is a semidirect product (it's a direct product).

Comment: This raises a question I was trying to formulate for OP:  what qualifies as the atoms in such a classification?  Certainly a cyclic group is fine w/o being a semi-direct product.

Comment: @Randall Are you talking about $\mathbb{Z}_4$?  If you take the short exact sequence corresponding to the normal subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_2$, there is no section, so the group is not a semidirect product in this way.

Comment: Agreed, the classification is tricky.  There are some orders where it is easy, e.g., $pq$.  However, for a "random" order, I would guess that there are non-semidirect products.

Answer (score 0):

No, not necessarily.  Semi-direct products have a normal subgroup as a factor, but finite simple groups cannot (non-trivially).  The first such group you typically encounter (besides $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $p$ a prime) is the alternating group $A_n$. For $n \geq 5$ the group $A_n$ is simple and so cannot admit an interesting semi-direct decomposition into smaller factors.

Comment: Thanks! So what are the conditions needed for us to be able to classify every groups of that particular order using a semi-direct product? (In the case of A5, it is simple - so can we still use semi-direct product to classify groups of order 30 then?)

Comment: I don't know.  I wouldn't be shocked if the answer is not known.

Comment: No.  Even if you count simple groups and cyclic groups as building blocks you can't express everything as an iterated semi-direct product.  The smallest counter-example is the quaternion group of order 8, which is not a semidirect product.  You would also have trouble with $SL(2,5)$, which is a double-cover of $A_5$ but does not split as a semidirect product.